# Virtual Hosts On Apache with host name for Intranet

Tags: networking, dns, apache-http-server, virtual-host, intranet

I’ve been having trouble wrapping my head around what I need to do here at work so this will be my attempt to do so.

I have a server for my own usage where I have a WAMP server running, and I’ve figured out how to get it online and navigate to it. The goal is to make it Intranet only and I’ve found that as well I believe (first 3 parts of the IP in the required section in `httpd.conf` file) and tested that. With that in mind I have 2 projects that I would like to host on there using the same IP address and then have them accessible by the host name from people within the company.

So if I name them `projectA` and `projectB` I have the two virtual hosts with servername `projectA` and `projectB` included in the httpd.conf file on the server. Also because of something we run at work I have it listening to port 8080 instead of port 80.

For short term testing I have my laptop with an entry in the hosts file mapping the IP address to the host name I’m going for, let’s call it `hostC`.

What I would like to be able to do is access `projectA` and `projectB` on `hostC` as a reasonable process by typing something like `//hostC/projectA/projectA/fileA.php` into the search bar, but what I’ve seen shows server names as only something like `www.projectA.com` which would then take it out from the host banner. So can I do what I want or am I thinking of it in the entirely wrong way?

My thoughts if what I’m doing is wrong are that either I would need to have two hosts mapped in my host file (will be represented in the company’s DNS server) and have it be more like `//hostA/projectAindex.php` and `//hostB/projectBindex.php` or just keep it as one host and provide a page which forks off to the two different projects like `//hostA/projectAindex.php` and `//hostA/projectBindex.php`. Does one of those make more sense?

I’ve read a lot about it, and gone through the Apache documentation I’m just not entirely sure what it means or how to think about it.

Comment: The whole point of name-based virtual hosts is so you can access different sites on the same server according to their hostname. If you don't *want* to access the server by the hostname (e.g. http://projectA/) then there's no point in name-based virtual hosting. If all you want is http://hostC/projectA then what you need is folders, not virtual hosts.

Comment: It might be.  We have two locations with different subnets, and I need to get it accessible only from them.  I put my WAMP online, and limited it to my particular location's subnet, so I believe that just adding the second one to the apache CONF file will get me what I want with it being on the intranet.  If I'm completely off let me know, and thanks for the input already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access `HostC` as a hostname (e.g. `hostc.local`) from anything other than a computer with a modified hosts file, you will have to set up a DNS server to map this name to your web server's IP address.

If HostC can be the IP address of the server, then you can just use that.

Assuming either case, you can put sub-folders (`ProjectA` and `ProjectB`) in HostC (your web server) to access `http://HostC/ProjectA/fileA.php` and `http://HostC/ProjectB/index.php`. You do not need virtual hosts for this.

If you want `http://HostA/ProjectA/fileA.php` and `http://HostB/ProjectB/index.php`, then you will need to define HostA and HostB in DNS (to access them from any computer without a modified hosts file, assuming you do not wish to access them via IP address/port combinations). You will need use virtual host entries assuming HostA and HostB both map to the web server on `HostC`. You will only need to map HostC in this case if you want to access `HostC` as a local domain name, not an IP address.

You may want virtual hosts as well to access services via reverse proxyies to map, say, something like `http://HostD:80/directoryD/` to `HostD:8080/directoryF/` or ex. `123.123.123.123`.